# How to split a string into parts of equal length in dart/flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to split a string into parts of length 4 in Dart/Flutter.

The best way to do this is by using a regular expression if I'm not wrong. Based on my regex knowledge and digging around I've settled on this regex `/.{1,4}(?=(.{4})+(?!.))|.{1,4}$/g`. However, I can't figure out how to use it in dart

**Here's what I have so far.**

```dart
String cardNum = "4444444444444444";
List<String> cardNums=cardNum.split(
        RegExp(r".{1,4}(?=(.{4})+(?!.))|.{1,4}$"));
```

I've already tested [regexr](https://regexr.com/4hc3m)

I expect `cardNums` to be `["4444","4444","4444","4444"]`

Instead I'm getting `[, , , , ]`

Comment: Don't you want to *match*? Use `.allMatches`

Comment: Why reopen? Don't `RegExp rx = new RegExp(r".{1,4}(?=(.{4})+(?!.))|.{1,4}$");` and then `rx.allMatches(cardNum).map((m) => m.group(0))` solve the issue? Of course, you may streamline the pattern (like replace `(?!.)` with `$`) further, but the point is you need to match, not split.